# Checking previous metadata deployments

Tags: deployment, metadata, ant

So I'm playing with deploys using the metadata API and I have 2 questions.

1. I noticed that when you deploy using metadata the deploy name in "Deployment Status" is just an Id, can I change the name?
2. I also couldn't find what was inside the deploys. Is there anywhere I can check what was deployed in each package?

Comment: Crashzilla, as per my knowledge answer to both of your question is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Out of the box - no. Metadata deployments are [tracked via an Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm). 
   You can create custom object(s) and custom screen(s) to manage a metadata deployment. For example, one custom object could map the deployment Id to your custom deployment name.
2. Yes. When you deploy metadata via `deploy()`, there's a `performRetrieve` flag that when set to `true` allows you to retrieve the metadata package details when the deployment is done. To grab these details, you have to [make another call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_checkdeploystatus.htm) via `checkDeployStatus()` and set `includeDetails` flag to `true`. With both flags on both of these calls set to `true`, the deployment details are available in `DeployResult` (see `details -> RetrieveResult -> fileProperties`)

Comment: Thanks for the info.